# Notify User about new update of application in app store as a alert and automatically install updated version in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, app-store, uialertview

Currently my application with version 1.1 is available in app store.

**Current Scenario:** when i update new version update is shown in app store when user goes to app store.

**Required:** As soon as user starts application alert should be popped up and if new version is available in app store it should **automatically install that if user clicks OK**.

Please suggest me the way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't make it install automatically, you can send the user to the app store app with your itunes app url.

Also you will need to make you're own webservice to check if a new version is available.

Comment: You don't need your own webservice, just use the one provided by iTunes : http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html