# How to alert user of new update of iOS app

Tags: ios, app-store, version, alert

Once I upload the app in AppStore, how can I alert the users whenever I release a new version of the app? I want them to be able to get an alert saying there is a new version available? What is the required code to insert before I submit it to AppStore?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Notify User about new update of application in app store as a alert and automatically install updated version in iPhone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7333722/notify-user-about-new-update-of-application-in-app-store-as-a-alert-and-automati)

Comment: Thank you for the link and suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't worry there is no code required. I've recently updated my app and I was wondering the same thing. It should do it automatically once the new version is on the store. A small red icon will appear in the top right of the App Store app icon. ;)

Comment: Thank you. I'll stick to this automatic icon alert.

Comment: If I have not enable automatic update. Then how can I get update from app-store

Answer (score 1):

I found this framework, it allows you to show the user an update is available, and if you want you can force him to update -

https://github.com/ArtSabintsev/Siren

Answer (score 0):

You need to check App Store version with your current app version by following API and show alert:

For all the territory : http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?bundleId=com.xyz.abc

or

Specific country : http://itunes.apple.com/US/lookup?bundleId=com.xyz.abc